# MVC5 model not recory the text value of textbox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I don't know what I'm doing bad.

**Controller:**

```
public class PictureController : Controller
{
    // GET: Picture
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AddGroup()
    {
        ModelPhotoGroup p = new ModelPhotoGroup();
        return View(p);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddGroup(ModelPhotoGroup p)
    {
        return View(p);
    }
}
```

In AddGroup of HttpPost I get a p.GroupName = null but I'm writing text in the textbox

**View:**

```
@model Boda.WebUI.Models.ModelPhotoGroup

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}

<h2>Crear grupo de fotos</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="well">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.GroupName)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.GroupName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.GroupName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.GroupName)
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success" />
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cancelar y volver a la lista de Fotografias", "Index", null, new
                   {
                       @class = "btn btn-default"
                   })
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the view. Only I have one TextBoxt to write the name of group

**HTML Generated:**

```
<form action="/Picture/AddGroup" method="post"><input id="GroupName" name="GroupName" type="hidden" value="">                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="GroupName">GroupName</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="GroupName" name="GroupName" type="text" value="">
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GroupName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Picture">Cancelar y volver a la lista de Fotografias</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.GroupName)
```

before

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.GroupName)
```

The value of the hidden input will be whatever the default value of `GroupName` was when you initialized the model (i.e. `null`)

When you POST, the `DefaultModelBinder` sets the value of property `GroupName` to the first value it reads from the form data (that of the hidden input) and ignores any subsequent values with the same name, so the property is always `null`.

Remove the hidden input and your model will be correctly bound with the value in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you did not specify the action and controller,
add the name of action and controller in your form

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddGroup","Picture"))
```